# C++ derived class method calls

Tags: c++

I'm trying to have my derived class call both the myC, and myB version of the print() method. I will be calling these methods from the indicator object of type myA. How do I do this in C++?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class myC
{
public:
  myC()  { }
  void print()
  {
    cout<<"Class C print."<<endl;
  }
};

class myB: myC
{
public:
  myB()  { }
  void print()
  {
    cout<<"Class B print."<<endl;
  }
};

class myA: myB
{
public:
  myA()  { }
  void print()
  {
    cout<<"Class A print."<<endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
    myA indicator();
    indicator.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can call myB::print() and myC::print() from myA.

Comment: Remove the `()` from `myA indicator();` - Currently it should not even compile - most vexing ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse ).

Comment: Keep reading your book. It explains this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need to inherit using some access specifier like `public` `protected` `private`

Change your inheritance to

```
class myB:public myC
{
....
}

class myA:public myB
{
....
}
```

Now in `main` call them using their classname

```
int main()
{
    myA indicator;
    indicator.print();
    indicator.myB::print();  //Note that indicator is object of only 
    indicator.myC::print();  //class myA but access myB,myC's print
    return 0;
}
```

**Note** you can call these functions if you have inherited using `public` access specifier,because inheriting using `public` means you can access those functions outside of class, and hence can call these functions in `main` or anywhere outside the class.
 For `protected` refer Kerek sb answer.

> Output

```
Class A print.
Class B print.
Class C print.
```

Comment: You don't need an access specifier while inheriting. Private inheritance (`: private class_name`) is default one. You should mention why `public` inheriting works here, while `private` or default one do not. Regarding rest of the answer: +1

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
void myA::print()
{
    cout<<"Class A print."<<endl;
    myB::print();
    myC::print();
}
```

This requires that the base classes are accessible from the derived class, i.e. they must be derived either as protected or as public.